# try catch statement in PHP where the file does not upload

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I understand what try-catch statements do, but from reading the documentation on php.net, I would not be able to implement one into my own code. I need a real example to help me understand.

How can I turn this example into a try-catch statement, if the upload was not successful?

```
$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);

if (!$move) {
    die ('File didn\'t upload');
} else {            
    //opens the uploaded file for extraction
    echo 'Upload Complete!';
}
```

This may not be a good example to work with, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087365

Answer (score 52):

You could do it like this.

```
try {
    //throw exception if can't move the file
    if (!move_uploaded_file( ... )) {
        throw new Exception('Could not move file');
    }

    //do some more things with the file which may also throw an exception
    //...

    //ok if got here
    echo "Upload Complete!";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die ('File did not upload: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

It is a bit pointless for the above example, but you should get the idea. Note that you can throw the exception(s) from anywhere (e.g. within a function/method that you call from withing the try{}) and they will propagate upwards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and answer! I understand this wasn't a great example. When would it be suitable to use an Exception? thanks!

Comment: I don't thin there are good or bad examples. Try/Catch statements are useful, when they are useful.

The only thing you should matter, is php will throw E_ERROR or E_WARNING when a function is misused.

Answer (score 9):

Well, if you want to use exceptions, you could do something like:

```
function handleUpload() {


    $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name']);

    if (!$move) {
       throw new Exception('File Didnt Upload');
    }

}

try {
   handleUpload();
   echo "File Uploaded Successfully";
} catch(Exception $ex) {
   die($ex->getMessage);
}
```

I know this may seem like bloat - but you can call the method from anywhere in the call stack, and catch the exception at any point.

Comment: Just a note, that exception handling is a lot more useful if you have a class hierarchy for your exceptions.  It's generally useful to use catch with specific Exception sub-classes, and this way you can choose what problems are handled at what level of the code.

Answer (score 7):

`try-catch` statements are used to handle exceptions. I don't believe that the function `move_uploaded_files` can throw and exception, as such I think that you code is written is correct. After the call, you look at the return code. If it's false, you end processing, otherwise you are report success.

Comment: His example is correct but I think the point was that he's trying to learn about exceptions rather than trying to fix/improve the sample code.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your quick responses! This seems to not be the best example to learn from. When would be a good/right time to use an Exception then?

Answer (score 4):

According to a similar post in PHPbug, only OO code (Object-Oriented code) throws exceptions. That would mean that functions such as move_uploaded_file won't throw their own exceptions, but some other code will.

Comment: This is important that "only OO code (Object-Oriented code) throws exceptions."  if you want to use it in directly a php functions (out of  any class) you won't get throw message...