# Can I try/catch a warning?

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

I need to catch some warnings being thrown from some php native functions and then handle them.

Specifically:

```
array dns_get_record  ( string $hostname  [, int $type= DNS_ANY  [, array &$authns  [, array &$addtl  ]]] )
```

It throws a warning when the DNS query fails.

`try`/`catch` doesn't work because a warning is not an exception.

I now have 2 options:

1. `set_error_handler` seems like overkill because I have to use it to filter every warning in the page (is this true?);
2. Adjust error reporting/display so these warnings don't get echoed to screen, then check the return value; if it's `false`, no records is found for hostname.

What's the best practice here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php is a good discussion regarding things like this.

Comment: there was an answer below that got deleted? either by owner or by someone?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087365

Comment: @user121196: Yes. By the owner.

Answer (score 429, accepted):

**Set and restore error handler**

One possibility is to set your own error handler before the call and restore the previous error handler later with `restore_error_handler()`.

```
set_error_handler(function() { /* ignore errors */ });
dns_get_record();
restore_error_handler();
```

You could build on this idea and write a re-usable error handler that logs the errors for you.

```
set_error_handler([$logger, 'onSilencedError']);
dns_get_record();
restore_error_handler();
```

**Turning errors into exceptions**

You can use `set_error_handler()` and the `ErrorException` class to turn all php errors into exceptions.

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    // error was suppressed with the @-operator
    if (0 === error_reporting()) {
        return false;
    }
    
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
});

try {
    dns_get_record();
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    // ...
}
```

The important thing to note when using your own error handler is that it will bypass the `error_reporting` setting and pass all errors (notices, warnings, etc.) to your error handler. You can set a second argument on `set_error_handler()` to define which error types you want to receive, or access the current setting using `... = error_reporting()` inside the error handler.

**Suppressing the warning**

Another possibility is to suppress the call with the @ operator and check the return value of `dns_get_record()` afterwards. **But I'd advise against this** as errors/warnings are triggered to be handled, not to be suppressed.

Comment: is it advisable to set my own error handler right before the function call, then restore_error_handler when the error checking is done?

Comment: will this be thread safe if there are many concurrent requests, and each request does 1.set_error_handler(). 2.doit 3.restore_error_handler ?

Comment: 1. if this is good practice? I really don't know. but if the dudes from Zend use this method, it can't really be that bad. 2. each request is self-contained, so there wont be any problem.

Comment: +1 for the avoidance of using @ to suppress errors. E_WARNING is actually a non-fatal error. In general you should always try to handle errors appropriately. If your application requires the usage of set_error_handler then do so. It is usually advisable to log errors and disable the display of them in a production environment. Upon checking the logs you can see where to make changes in your development environment. Too many instances where I've seen @fopen/@unlink and wonder why the developer didn't perform checks to avoid the errors or handle the error using set_error_handler.

Comment: A note about turning warnings into exceptions: a warning won't abort your app—an *uncaught* exception will do!

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: If you turn *everything* into exceptions, even a E_NOTICE will abort your app - and those are emitted in unexpected (undocumented) locations. For example, this seems all clean and functional, but also emits notices: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apcu-fetch.php

Comment: Note that if you intend to temporarily set the error handler and catch/throw the exceptions, you should put the `restore_error_handler()` in a `finally`, otherwise it might not get reset.

Comment: Will set_error_handler install a global error handler or only for my very script that is currently running? If it's the latter, why bother calling restore_error_handler at all? If it's the former, this solution has 1000 problems.

Comment: Just a note that for PHP8, you may have other options https://stackoverflow.com/a/69849208/1548557

Comment: @MrMesees this only works with TypeError and ValueError (e.g. providing bad input arguments). but it won't work with warnings due to runtime errors. See https://3v4l.org/p2Eka as an example.

Comment: `error_reporting()` doesn't return `0` if errors are suppressed in PHP 8. [See my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77566058/2415524)

Answer (score 178):

The solution that really works turned out to be setting simple error handler with `E_WARNING` parameter, like so:

```
set_error_handler("warning_handler", E_WARNING);
dns_get_record(...)
restore_error_handler();

function warning_handler($errno, $errstr) { 
// do something
}
```

Comment: also anonymous `callable` can be used here instead of string with function declaration

Comment: Thanks, but how can I remove error-handler after the critical block?

Comment: Excellent! Just `trow new \Exception($errstr, $errno);` inside `warning_handler` function. Thanks.

Comment: This is the best answer here!

Answer (score 34):

**Be careful with the `@` operator** - while it suppresses warnings it also suppresses fatal errors. I spent a lot of time debugging a problem in a system where someone had written `@mysql_query( '...' )` and the problem was that mysql support was not loaded into PHP and it threw a silent fatal error. It will be safe for those things that are part of the PHP core but *please* use it with care.

```
bob@mypc:~$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo @something(); // this will just silently die...
```

No further output - good luck debugging this!

```
bob@mypc:~$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo something(); // lets try it again but don't suppress the error
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function something() in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
bob@mypc:~$
```

This time we can see why it failed.

Comment: Since PHP 7, fatal errors are not suppressed. @ operator just suppresses warnings and notice.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to try/catch a warning, but at the same time keep the usual warning/error logging (e.g. in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`); for which the handler has to return `false`. However, since the "throw new..." statement basically interrupts the execution, one then has to do the "wrap in function" trick, also discussed in:

[Is there a static way to throw exception in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905867/is-there-a-static-way-to-throw-exception-in-php/4905889#4905889)

Or, in brief:

```
  function throwErrorException($errstr = null,$code = null, $errno = null, $errfile = null, $errline = null) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
  }
  function warning_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext) {
    return false && throwErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
    # error_log("AAA"); # will never run after throw
    /* Do execute PHP internal error handler */
    # return false; # will never run after throw
  }
  ...
  set_error_handler('warning_handler', E_WARNING);
  ...
  try {
    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    // ...
  }
```

---

EDIT: after closer inspection, it turns out it doesn't work: the "`return false && throwErrorException ...`" will, basically, *not* throw the exception, and just log in the error log; removing the "`false &&`" part, as in "`return throwErrorException ...`", will make the exception throwing work, but will then not log in the error_log... I'd still keep this posted, though, as I haven't seen this behavior documented elsewhere.

Comment: And how can we like revert this change ?

Comment: As per boolean evaluation logic `return false && ` will never look beyond `&&` because encountering `false` in a `&&` chain once is enough to be certain it remains `false`. Thus, neither literals, nor variables, nor functions will be evaluated afterwards. So the order becomes important. If anything, make it `return func() && false`. This is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 5):

Combining these lines of code around a `file_get_contents()` call to an external url helped me handle warnings like "**failed to open stream: Connection timed out**" much better:

```
set_error_handler(function ($err_severity, $err_msg, $err_file, $err_line, array $err_context)
{
    throw new ErrorException( $err_msg, 0, $err_severity, $err_file, $err_line );
}, E_WARNING);
try {
    $iResult = file_get_contents($sUrl);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->sErrorMsg = $e->getMessage();
}
restore_error_handler();
```

This solution works within object context, too. You could use it in a function:

```
public function myContentGetter($sUrl)
{
  ... code above ...
  return $iResult;
}
```

Comment: The final parameter in the handler function (`$err_context`) has been removed in PHP 8 (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Answer (score 4):

Normaly you should never use @ unless this is the only solution. In that specific case the function dns_check_record should be use first to know if the record exists.

Answer (score 3):

If `dns_get_record()` fails, it should return `FALSE`, so you can suppress the warning with `@` and then check the return value.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably try to get rid of the warning completely, but if that's not possible, you can prepend the call with @ (i.e. @dns_get_record(...)) and then use any information you can get to figure out if the warning happened or not.

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP8, you can do the following instead of setting error handlers to catch Errors. I Believe in PHP 7..something you could catch some Errors.

```
try {
    call_user_func('sprintf', array_merge([$string], $args));
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    $logger->info('mesage...');
}
```

You should generally be somewhere that you can pass or access a logger if you bulkhead in this way, as it can obfuscate coder errors, such as passing incorrectly typed parameters to a method, and mask a variety of other problems.

https://php.watch/versions/8.0/internal-function-exceptions

Not sure if notices are caught (likely not), but you can likely solve around examples like this one, by thinking a little more about what you are looking to do.

Both builder pattern, and options patterns provide solutions for this where prior to the site of call, which can be a private function or just after validity checks, you can throw a real custom exception that is attributable only to your code. That will make even built-in functions very safe to use.

One other nice practice is to use either `debug_backtrace`, with `DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS` or use the `getTrace` or `getTraceAsString` methods on the Throwable so that some of the context is preseved.

Comment: Warnings do not throw a `\Throwable`, so they won't be caught. [Proof of concept code](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724IKNgwYKlpSVpuhY33WzsgVyukqJKhWouBQWVCgVbBZXEaMNYa65aruTEkuQMBY2YkIyi_PLEpJxUBZVUTbC61OSMfAV158TS9IwSdaBSiGlQQ2GGAwA)

Comment: Thanks, here is a different link which confirms my misunderstanding and @mbomb007 correctness. https://3v4l.org/A5OmL#veol

Answer (score 1):

try checking whether it returns some boolean value then you can simply put it as a condition. I encountered this with the oci_execute(...) which was returning some violation with my unique keys.

```
ex.
oci_parse($res, "[oracle pl/sql]");
if(oci_execute){
...do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**FolderStructure**

```
index.php //Script File
logs //Folder for log Every warning and Errors
CustomException.php //Custom exception File
```

**CustomException.php**

```
/**
* Custom error handler
*/
function handleError($code, $description, $file = null, $line = null, $context = null) {
    $displayErrors = ini_get("display_errors");;
    $displayErrors = strtolower($displayErrors);
    if (error_reporting() === 0 || $displayErrors === "on") {
        return false;
    }
    list($error, $log) = mapErrorCode($code);
    $data = array(
        'timestamp' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s:u", time()),
        'level' => $log,
        'code' => $code,
        'type' => $error,
        'description' => $description,
        'file' => $file,
        'line' => $line,
        'context' => $context,
        'path' => $file,
        'message' => $error . ' (' . $code . '): ' . $description . ' in [' . $file . ', line ' . $line . ']'
    );
    $data = array_map('htmlentities',$data);
    return fileLog(json_encode($data));
}

/**
* This method is used to write data in file
* @param mixed $logData
* @param string $fileName
* @return boolean
*/
function fileLog($logData, $fileName = ERROR_LOG_FILE) {
    $fh = fopen($fileName, 'a+');
    if (is_array($logData)) {
        $logData = print_r($logData, 1);
    }
    $status = fwrite($fh, $logData . "\n");
    fclose($fh);
//    $file = file_get_contents($filename);
//    $content = '[' . $file .']';
//    file_put_contents($content); 
    return ($status) ? true : false;
}

/**
* Map an error code into an Error word, and log location.
*
* @param int $code Error code to map
* @return array Array of error word, and log location.
*/
function mapErrorCode($code) {
    $error = $log = null;
    switch ($code) {
        case E_PARSE:
        case E_ERROR:
        case E_CORE_ERROR:
        case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
        case E_USER_ERROR:
            $error = 'Fatal Error';
            $log = LOG_ERR;
            break;
        case E_WARNING:
        case E_USER_WARNING:
        case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
        case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
            $error = 'Warning';
            $log = LOG_WARNING;
            break;
        case E_NOTICE:
        case E_USER_NOTICE:
            $error = 'Notice';
            $log = LOG_NOTICE;
            break;
        case E_STRICT:
            $error = 'Strict';
            $log = LOG_NOTICE;
            break;
        case E_DEPRECATED:
        case E_USER_DEPRECATED:
            $error = 'Deprecated';
            $log = LOG_NOTICE;
            break;
        default :
            break;
    }
    return array($error, $log);
}
//calling custom error handler
set_error_handler("handleError");
```

just include above file into your script file like this

**index.php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
define('ERROR_LOG_FILE', 'logs/app_errors.log');

include_once 'CustomException.php';
echo $a; // here undefined variable warning will be logged into logs/app_errors.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to PHP 8, suppressing errors would cause `error_reporting()` to return `0` inside an error handler. As of PHP 8, it will instead return the value of [`E_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_USER_ERROR | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR | E_PARSE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), which equals `4437`.

If you are worried about it changing in the future and don't want to paste that long constant or the value `4437`, you can use `@error_reporting()` instead, which will return the desired suppression value.

```php
/**
 * Custom error handler to make warnings and notices into exceptions.
 *
 * @param int $errno
 *   The level of the error raised.
 * @param string $errstr
 *   The error message.
 * @param string $errfile
 *   The filename that the error was raised in.
 * @param int $errline
 *   The line number where the error was raised.
 *
 * @return false
 *   If the error was suppressed or no exception should be thrown.
 *
 * @throws \ErrorException
 */
function custom_error_handler(int $errno, string $errstr, string $errfile, int $errline): false {
  // Error was suppressed with the @-operator
  if (error_reporting() === @error_reporting()) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
```

[Run this proof of concept code online.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVLNSsNAEAaPeYrvUGgKbfUo1moFKx7UFvQiCCWkk-5C2A27E6JI38A38FIQH0qfxklCY2ovHgKZ4eP723n_yFS22XzmnAyOvw_eTs9lDoIkNzFra0DOWbdQkVmm5EJtGB1ZGduHZ6fNqhrld2dOdEp9bMGpNtQ7QRKlnvAaAIeHmJa0KCIPn2eZI-9piUKzAivCZGAzchFbJ2idIKxdOMqsYxEJexiPx5jsrXsVP-CIc2dwdXFzPx3JZi0fK2cLGCpq8elzTFkZMWwSbJMd9VspmgSjYB0EnnixW0l3Z-wKLJB8D0p7NCUWOk2xIlNmIkSS2xnxO_ytmclzWLvvPGOMDldywnTf9DMM2L1UkEkNLyFxxLFC-NTEEcM1D8XKovtoc3hl83QJYxmeSIrQftjFEPPr-WI6uxltwR0anK2Ib0UtWlHNX1q4mz20nunXxr9d_CVua4uE8MpT059ie6P6KL8uK479E2iRVIj9c2hBaq7tof8A)

You can also try running code at https://3v4l.org to run it on different PHP versions.

Here is an overly complicated function I made that will also get the suppression constant.

```php
function get_suppression_constant(): int {
  $suppressed = 0;

  // Set an error handler that will get the suppression constant.
  set_error_handler(function () use (&$suppressed) {
    $suppressed = error_reporting();
    return FALSE;
  });
  // Trigger a suppressed error to get the constant.
  @(function () {
    trigger_error('Getting suppression constant.', E_USER_NOTICE);
  })();
  // Restore the original error handler.
  restore_error_handler();

  return $suppressed;
}
```

But as I discovered, you can simply just call `@error_reporting()` to get it.

Answer (score -1):

I would only recommend using @ to suppress warnings when it's a straight forward operation (e.g. $prop = @($high/($width - $depth)); to skip division by zero warnings). However in most cases it's better to handle.

Comment: This is one time you definitely don't want to use @ - you have control over the operation and can check if it's a division by zero or not before doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Since PHP7 you can catch most errors and warnings like so:

```
try {
    whatever();
} catch (Throwable $e) {
}
```

More: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php