# Server-side cache with MemCache in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2, memcached

I have in my config web

```
'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 11211,
                'weight' => 60,
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

and a form with email. In my controller, I want to cache the count of how many time the same email posted.

```
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
    $counter = \Yii::$app->cache->get('antiflood-'.$model->email);
    if($counter === false){
        \Yii::$app->cache->set('antiflood-'..$model->email,1,86400);
    } else {
        \Yii::$app->cache->set('antiflood-'.$model->email,$counter+1,86400);
    }
    var_dump(Yii::$app->cache->get(''antiflood-'.$model->email));
    exit;
}
```

After I submit form, count is increased.If I refresh my page, I have confirmation from chrome and I see

[image]

If I click continue it's working fine. But if I go back to form and enter same email, I see again 1 output i.e again go to if condition but need to go to else because I already set id with same email. What is wrong here? Can anyone suggest me.
Thank You.

Comment: Are you 100% sure `$model->email` is `5001@direktpoint.pl`?

Comment: Check if memcache works at all.

Comment: @BIzley Please see the edit. I try to put hardcore email in place $model->email and is with same result.

Comment: Check if `Yii::$app->cache->set()` returns `true` and if it's not the case check if memcache server works.

Comment: I see if I var_dump(\Yii::$app->cache->get('antiflood-'.$model->email)) just before post and fill my form with same email. My output is always bool(false).And how can I check memcache server is working or not?

Comment: Run `ps aux | grep memcache` and see if there is anything.

Comment: I don't have access to server terminal but I checked with var_dump(class_exists('Memcache')). Its return me true.

Comment: Run code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11061667/3364821).

Comment: Is the same if I fill up my data and submit I will always have fresh data in output.

Comment: Have you run the code I linked? Do you see `Memcache seem to be working fine!`?

Comment: Yap I see Memcache seem to be working fine! in last line of output.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how to help you in this case. You need to debug your code and see why cache `set()` is not working.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the key (as far as i know there are some limitations on the characters in the key) are you able te set a a value if create a hash from the key like ```\Yii::$app->cache->set(utf8_encode(md5('antiflood-'..$model->email)),1,86400);``` or  ```\Yii::$app->cache->set(md5('antiflood-'..$model->email),1,86400);```

Comment: @Tim I try but is same problem