# Can I Try-Catch PHP Warnings while loading an html file into DOMDocument?

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch, warnings, domdocument

Is it possible to do some sort of try catch that will catch warnings?

e.g.

```
if (!$dom->loadHTMLFile($url)) {
    //if cant load file handle error my way
}
```

For the `$url` I am using I am getting

> Warning (2): DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(MYURL) [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
>        [APP\controllers\import_controller.php, line 62]
>
> Warning (2): DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "hMYURL" [APP\controllers\import_controller.php, line 62]

**I could just suppress the error with `@`, and do something if the call returns `false`, but I want to be able to catch the exact warning message and then do something with it.**

**Is this possible?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [try and catch php warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/try-and-catch-php-warning)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) for this.

This example is adapted from the manual:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$res = $doc->loadHTMLFile($url); //this may fail and return FALSE!
foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
    // handle errors here
}
libxml_clear_errors();
```

No PHP notices will be emitted here.

Answer (score 6):

Probably you are looking for this

```
<?php
// error handler function
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
        echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
        echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
        exit(1);
        break;

    case E_USER_WARNING:
        echo "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    case E_USER_NOTICE:
        echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}

// function to test the error handling
function scale_by_log($vect, $scale)
{
    if (!is_numeric($scale) || $scale <= 0) {
        trigger_error("log(x) for x <= 0 is undefined, you used: scale = $scale", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    if (!is_array($vect)) {
        trigger_error("Incorrect input vector, array of values expected", E_USER_WARNING);
        return null;
    }

    $temp = array();
    foreach($vect as $pos => $value) {
        if (!is_numeric($value)) {
            trigger_error("Value at position $pos is not a number, using 0 (zero)", E_USER_NOTICE);
            $value = 0;
        }
        $temp[$pos] = log($scale) * $value;
    }

    return $temp;
}

// set to the user defined error handler
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

// trigger some errors, first define a mixed array with a non-numeric item
echo "vector a\n";
$a = array(2, 3, "foo", 5.5, 43.3, 21.11);
print_r($a);

// now generate second array
echo "----\nvector b - a notice (b = log(PI) * a)\n";
/* Value at position $pos is not a number, using 0 (zero) */
$b = scale_by_log($a, M_PI);
print_r($b);

// this is trouble, we pass a string instead of an array
echo "----\nvector c - a warning\n";
/* Incorrect input vector, array of values expected */
$c = scale_by_log("not array", 2.3);
var_dump($c); // NULL

// this is a critical error, log of zero or negative number is undefined
echo "----\nvector d - fatal error\n";
/* log(x) for x <= 0 is undefined, you used: scale = $scale" */
$d = scale_by_log($a, -2.5);
var_dump($d); // Never reached
?>
```

this will make this output:

```
vector a
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => foo
    [3] => 5.5
    [4] => 43.3
    [5] => 21.11
)
----
vector b - a notice (b = log(PI) * a)
<b>My NOTICE</b> [1024] Value at position 2 is not a number, using 0 (zero)<br />
Array
(
    [0] => 2.2894597716988
    [1] => 3.4341896575482
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 6.2960143721717
    [4] => 49.566804057279
    [5] => 24.165247890281
)
----
vector c - a warning
<b>My WARNING</b> [512] Incorrect input vector, array of values expected<br />
NULL
----
vector d - fatal error
<b>My ERROR</b> [256] log(x) for x <= 0 is undefined, you used: scale = -2.5<br />
  Fatal error on line 35 in file trigger_error.php, PHP 5.2.1 (FreeBSD)<br />
Aborting...<br />
```

[Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a [custom error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) but I am not completely sure if the warnings you get can be handled. Some errors or warnings will always use the default error handler. But just try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a very attractive solution at http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/6296-catch-warnings:

First tell PHP to track all errors:

```
ini_set('track_errors', '1');
```

This puts all error messages (incl. warnings) into the variable `$php_errormsg` (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.track-errors).

Then you can catch errors and warnings like this:

```
if (!@copy('no_file', 'some_file')) {
  echo $php_errormsg, "\n";
}
```