# PHP alternatives to handling malformed input instead of throwing errors

Tags: php, error-handling

There are many functions (well most really) in the PHP language that get all upset and throw warnings and notices when they don't like something about their input - rather than just returning `FALSE` (though they do that too).

One place this is really common is in the GD and string functions. They are very particular about their arguments and it's really easy for user input to fail meeting their standards.

For example, a user uploads a image that is corrupt (intentionally or unintentionally). Resulting in warnings from the GD library.

So far there are only three ways I have found to silence PHP on this issue:

- Change your error reporting setting in the ini or [at runtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) (*yuck*).
- Suppress errors with the slow `@` symbol.
- Change error reporting right before/after the function:

like so:

```
$errorlevel=error_reporting();
error_reporting($errorlevel & ~E_NOTICE);
//...code that generates notices
error_reporting($errorlevel);
```

Naturally, the second two choices just make me sick. Which leaves me using 1) and toning down the PHP error settings. However, I want PHP to be in strict mode so that while I'm working I can catch logic bugs and bad form that might creep into my code. However, I don't want to have random errors thrown when PHP doesn't like something.

**So is there any way to separate errors that are from malformed arguments (bad input) from errors that are from bad programming?** For example:

1. If a user image is invalid just return FALSE and I'll deal with it. I don't need warnings.
2. If my passing of an image resource to print function is invalid throw warnings.

Comment: All of the GD imagecreate* functions should already return false on error, or are you using something else?

Comment: @tadamson Many GD functions also throw a warning/notice in addition to returning false: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: @tadamson As I mention above, they do return FALSE. However, they also throw E_WARNINGS which cannot be caught right there and analyzed like an exception or boolean result can.

Comment: Ah, sorry - haven't used gd in a long time.  Might not answer your question at all, but: since the imagick lib is OO-based, you can play catch with ImagickExceptions instead.  Changing from one to the other is a hassle though.

Answer (score 3):

There's another alternative - use `set_error_handler()`, you can even call it just before the GD function call and return to the default with `restore_error_handler()`.

There's a good comment in the question [try and catch a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/try-and-catch-a-warning/1241751#1241751) that gives more detail on how this is accomplished.

Comment: Yes, I actually *used* to do this. However, adding a try {} catch {} block for each function would increase the size of the codebase dramatically. Each 1 line function now = 5 lines of code. Plus it also slow the code down considerably since handling exceptions take more time than just checking `$result === FALSE`

Comment: You don't have to use try/catch for every function, you can use `add_exception_handler()` to set up a default handler for all exceptions.

Comment: But if I setup a global handler then how do I tie that back to the code I was running when it happened? I have to catch the exception right there in order to deal with it - or else makeup a cumbersome events system that does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ill-design from the beginnings of PHP. A modern PHP library would throw an exception on error. And an exception may be caught. But back then GD was written PHP didn't yet support exceptions.

Thus I think that in this case it **is** legitimate to use the `@` operator.

Comment: Throwing exceptions would also be ok with me since I can handle them just the same way I would for a boolean FALSE check on the function result. To bad it doesn't throw something that is catchable...

Answer (score 1):

## Fix the code

Sanitize the input *before* you call the functions. This saves you errors.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to gauge if an image file is valid until I attempt to open it with GD. If GD can't read it *then I know it's invalid*.

Comment: Xeoncross, in that case, exceptions are needed. Of course, PHP won't help you natively.

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic approach for all libraries besides editing the offending library and changing how it throws exceptions. Honeslty, a lot of PHP devs really didn't care about exceptions being thrown, but now more and more people are getting on the E_STRICT wagon. When the GD libs were generated the mentality probably was that throwing uncatchable errors wasn't that big a deal.

As far as the validating images with GD. The only thing you can really do is to use a different library or function to validate your images. You might [try using magic byte functions](http://pastebin.com/85e2SE9U) to check if the images have proper headers(though this doesn't mean the rest of the file is structured correctly). At least using the magic byte functions will take care of obvious things like someone uploading a text file instead of a JPEG.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just realizing a design choice that hopefully will change as PHP moves into heavier object-based world. However, I was hoping there might have been a better temporary solution for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

If there is something like that, you can use the [@-operator](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Its not a clean solution, but there are situations, where it's indispensable.

Did you check the image before using getimagesize() ?

Answer (score 0):

> However, I don't want to have random
>   errors thrown when PHP doesn't like
>   something.

Why not? PHP is trying to tell you something notable with warnings and notices. In the GD example you'll want to log when a user is uploading a corrupt file - especially if it's being used in an attack. [Turn of the display of error messages and log everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909102/php-alternatives-to-handling-malformed-input-instead-of-throwing-errors/3909184#3909184).

Comment: I think the biggest problem with not catching the errors is the user is thrown to a white or partially loaded screen with no clear explanation on what went wrong or what is going on. For an average user this would be pretty unsettling.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue as the functions also return false, which you can detect and output something other than a blank page. Warnings do not kill the execution of your script & you should not be outputting them on a production server.

Comment: Yes, throwing warning errors is unneeded if you check that the output of a GD function on a user image is `=== FALSE`. At that point you should know something is obviously wrong and log data about the situation yourself.