# Is there a static way to throw exception in php

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

Is there a "static" way of throwing an exception in php?

I need to throw an exception when a mysql query fails.

I tried this:

```
$re=@mysql_query( $query ) or throw new Exception(' Query Failed ');
```

but it's not working.

And I'm using a function based on the [`throwException()` function from this comment at **PHP: Exceptions manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#81960), but I would like to know if there is a static way for doing this without making a class.

Comment: What does "static" mean?

Comment: by static I mean without initializing a class

Comment: I hope that this useless ' Query Failed ' statement is just an example and in real you gonna put there an actual error along with query

Comment: @Shrapnel Yes, I used ' Query Failed ' Just as an example, in real I will be also placing the actual error with mysql_error()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to directly do `or throw new Exception();` because `throw` is a statement, not an expression. Since `or` is really an operator, it expects its operands to be expressions (things that evaluate to some values).

You'd have to do this instead:

```
$re = mysql_query($query);

if (!$re) {
    throw new Exception('Query Failed');
}
```

If you're trying to use the `throwException()` function proposed by that PHP manual comment, as webbiedave points out the comment is saying that you need to call that function instead of the `throw` statement directly, like this:

```
$re = mysql_query($query) or throwException('Query Failed');
```

There's no rule in PHP that says you need to throw exceptions from a class method. As long as there's some way to catch that exception you're fine. If you mean you want to throw exceptions without using the `Exception` class, well, you have to. Exceptions are objects by nature; you can't throw an exception that isn't an object (or doesn't inherit from the `Exception` class).

If you don't want to throw exceptions but raise the kind of error you often see from PHP (notices, warnings and fatal errors), use [`trigger_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php).

```
$re = mysql_query($query);

if (!$re) {
    trigger_error('Query Failed', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: Everything in imperative programming languages is a statement ;) `throw` is a language construct, so it's dealt with by parser and can't be evaluated runtime to some values, yes

Answer (score 7):

The comment you link to states that throwing an exception in this way will not work. It states you have to place it in a function:

```
function throwException($message = null, $code = null) {
    throw new Exception($message, $code);
}

$re = mysql_query($query) or throwException('Query Failed');
```

Comment: yeah it does.

I was looking for a way to do something like Exception::setMessage(' Message ');

But now I know it's not possible after BoltClock replied

Comment: @rados: And he's saying you call the function after `or`, but in your question you're calling the actual `throw` statement instead of the function.

Comment: @BoltClock yes, what I'm doing now is something like this:

$re=@mysql_query( $query) or IException::throwException(' Query Failed ');

IException is a class I made myself, I was looking for a pre-defined class instead of using my own one.

Answer (score 2):

You might also try something like

```
mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_error()) {
  throw new Exception(...);
}
```

as `mysql_error()` returns empty string if there was no error, which evaluates to `false`.