# Avoid DOMDocument XML warnings in php

Tags: php, warnings

I'm fetching xml files from a server and sometimes I'm getting a non-valid xml files, because of this I'm getting a warning:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in
```

How can I catch this warning and delete the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [try and catch a warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/try-and-catch-a-warning) (For the more broad answer)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have two choices. Either use the `@` error control operator in your `load()` call, e.g. `@$dom->load()`, which is somewhat slow because it globally changes the value of display_errors to off, executes the function and sets it back to on.

The other option, which I personally prefer (I hate the `@` operator, I can't stand to see it in my code) is to save the old value of [libxml_use_internal_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php), enable it using `libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE)`, call the function, clear the errors buffer and restore the old value. Here's a snippet from my code that does that:

```
<?php
$previous_value = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$doc->loadHTML((string)$e->response->getBody());
libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($previous_value);
```

I can't comment on answers yet, so I'll write it here:

- Michael solution makes it less strict, but it'll still issue warnings for some of the errors:

```
nadav@shesek:~$ php -r '$dom=new DOMDocument; $dom->strictErrorChecking = FALSE ; $dom->loadHTML("<xy></zx>");'
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag xy invalid in Entity, line: 1 in Command line code on line 1
```

- DON'T do what Fran Verona suggested - globally disabling error reporting is something you should never do. In production, set your own error handler and display a prettier message to the user, and make sure the error is logged somewhere - but never disable it completely. Setting error_reporting to 0 will cause PHP to disable error logging too.
- Xeon06 solution is problematic because you're effecting the entire script error handler for a specific piece of code. Using your own error handler that simply ignores the error causes the same issues as Fran's solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

```
set_error_handler("yourHandler", E_WARNING);
```

Comment: and use restore_error_handler() after the validation of the XML file.

Comment: Indeed, and thanks for the edit, I'm used to writting JS functions :)

Answer (score 2):

Turn off strict error checking:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->strictErrorChecking = FALSE ;

$dom->load('/path/to/file.xml');
if (!$dom->validate()) {
   // Invalid XML!
}
```

Comment: How can I know weather the xml is valid or not? If I'm getting this warning I want to delete the file and download again...

Comment: @iUngi See addition above `DOMDocument::validate()`