# CakePHP: How can I catch mkdir error?

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling

I am currently using the following code in CakePHP 1.3.10 (using PHP 5.2.17) when mkdir returns false:

```
CakeLog::write('error', "An error occurred while creating the \"$target_dir\" directory.");
```

I would like to also capture the exact error message such as:

```
Warning (2): mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists
```

I could then include that error message in the log. How can I do that with CakePHP? I've tried using the `error_get_last` function, but it just says:

```
Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That error doesn't come from `error_get_last()`. What's the exact code you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually trying to catch a warning. A method for that is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/try-and-catch-a-warning)

The function file_exists() does check for directory existence too. You could try that possibly