# PHP catch failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, oauth, error-handling, oauth-2.0

I am trying to do the following.

When I try to access a service using oAuth, if I get an error, because I am using a wrong key, I want to not show the error messages, but instead send the user to the authentication page.

However using a try catch fn does not work.

This is my code:

```
$url = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/me.json?'.http_build_query(array(
        'oauth_token' => $token,
    ));
    //
    try{
        $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
        return array(
            'uid' => $user->id,
            'nickname' => $user->username,
            'name' => $user->full_name,
            'location' => $user->country.' ,'.$user->country,
            'description' => $user->description,
            'image' => $user->avatar_url,
            'urls' => array(
                'MySpace' => $user->myspace_name,
                'Website' => $user->website,
            ),
        );
    }
    catch(Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e)
    {
        log_message('error', 'EXCEPTION: '.$e);
        return FALSE;
    }
```

I want this to either return the user array or FALSE.

Any ideas?

Comment: You try block is most likely NOT throwing that big long ugly exception. Since you're catching only that SPECIFIC exception, any other exception will just proceed on its way.

Comment: Does it work if you `catch (Exception $e)` instead?

Comment: may this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574130/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-404-not

Comment: It seems to be working with Exception $e now, I tried it before with not luck. Maybe it was cached or something. Thanks anyway, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look here for catching file_get_content error

[How can I handle the warning of file_get_contents() function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php)

That offers different solutions like looking at the response header

```
$content = @file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
if (strpos($http_response_header[0], "200")) { 
   echo "SUCCESS";
} else { 
   echo "FAILED";
}
```