# How to force file_get_contents to work

Tags: php, file-get-contents

It was a while that I use the function `file_get_contents` to get html data from a website. but today it dosen't, to see why I've used :

```
$html = @file_get_contents('http://www.thewebsite.com/');
if(!$html)
   exit( "Oops. Error :)" );
```

And this show me the error message. So perhaps they have prevent somehow the connection.

Please masters how could I force the function to get the contents ?

EDIT :

This give this error :

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.thewebsite.com/) 
       [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: 
       failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

**PS**  I've tried another website and this works fine

Comment: You forgot to read the documentation. Several reasons that `file_get_contents` may fail are listed there.

Comment: It doesn't show the important error message because you've suppressed it with `@`. Remove it and edit your question.

Comment: Perhaps it is _thewebsite_ which needs fixing.

Comment: Possible duplicate, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574130/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-404-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove warning suppression
2. Turn on error reporting
3. Check the messages in error_log
   You should see detailed error message instead of "Oops. Error." Then you will know why it doesn't work

Comment: Then try to google error message. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/file-get-contents-returning-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed

Answer (score 0):

According to manual page .
    A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. 
Did you really check if every url return false and gave error. Then obviously you need to check settings.