# WordPress Site Error failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: wordpress, http, http-status-code-404

I am trying to open a WordPress site on an external server for which I do not have a domain yet using its ip address and an adjusted HOST file on my Mac to check it on the server. When I access the site I get errors like:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://domain/folder/wp-content/themes/theme-name/img/phonehead.svg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/folder/wp-content/themes/theme-name/inc/control/file.php on line 16
```

I did find some articles on the same issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574130/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-404-not) one. The issues is not that the path is wrong or the file is not there. It seems that it has something to do with either my router or the way I use the hosts file to resolve the domain to the new ip address.

The hosts file line I added should be fine, so perhaps there is an issue with my D-Link DVG-N5412SP router is handling the request. But nowhere did I find how I can fix the issue. What do I need to adjust?

**Update**

From another location I got

```
 Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/folder/wp-content/themes/theme/inc/control/THeaderControl.php on line 16
```

This might point me to the right direction. Working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the path request local and not over the network I had to use the WordPress template tag `get_template_directory()` instead of `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` .