# store the PERMALINK in a PHP variable

Tags: php, variables

I have this code to count all the social sites shares in my posts. The problem with the code is the permalink is static.

If you noticed, i stored the permalink in `$myurl` variable using `get_permalink();`, the problem with the code is once I change the link "http://www.bendaggers.com/how-to-write-a-killer-resume-that-lands-an-interview/", it gives me tons of errors such as:

> file_get_contents(http://graph.facebook.com/?id=$myurl): failed to
>   open stream: HTTP request failed!

Here's my code:

```
$myurl = get_permalink();
$url = urlencode($url);

$facebook_like_share_count = function ( $url ) {
    $api = file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $url );
    $count = json_decode( $api );
    return $count->shares;
};


$twitter_tweet_count = function ( $url ) {
    $api = file_get_contents( 'https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $url );
    $count = json_decode( $api );
    return $count->count;
};


$pinterest_pins = function ( $url ) {
    $api = file_get_contents( 'http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback%20&url=' . $url );
    $body = preg_replace( '/^receiveCount\((.*)\)$/', '\\1', $api );
    $count = json_decode( $body );
    return $count->count;
};




echo twitter_tweet_count( 'http://www.bendaggers.com/how-to-write-a-killer-resume-that-lands-an-interview/' );

echo "<br>";

echo facebook_like_share_count( 'http://www.bendaggers.com/how-to-write-a-killer-resume-that-lands-an-interview/' );

echo "<br>";

echo pinterest_pins( 'http://www.bendaggers.com/how-to-write-a-killer-resume-that-lands-an-interview/' );

echo "<br>";


?>
```

To add, the `get_permalink` function returns the current URL of the active page. I'm doing this to integrate it to my wordpress website and show the exact number of shares (facebook, twitter, linkedin and pinterest). The code above doesnt return the URL of the current page. It's static.

Comment: Looking over these, it would appear you need to be calling `urlencode()` on the input `$url`.  So `$url = urlencode($url);` -- since it is used as a query string parameter in the API calls sent to `file_get_contents()`. This may not be the only thing causing problems though.

Comment: A note on style - what you have here works in most PHP versions, but appears to be heavily influenced by JavaScript function definition style. It's pretty alien for PHP. The function definitions would be more conventional as `function pinterest_pins($url) {...}`, and then called without a `$` as simply `pinterest_pins('http://...');`  rather than assigning functions to variables and calling via variable functions.

Comment: The weird thing about this code, if i used  echo twitter_tweet_count( "google.com");, echo facebook_like_share_count( "google.com);, it works perfectly. the errors will be displayed if i changed the static link to $myurl

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574130/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-404-not

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a few simple oversights to me.

The first is that `$url` is encoding a variable that doesn't exist. Currently you have

```
$myurl = get_permalink();
$url = urlencode($url);
```

... when it should probably be

```
$myurl = get_permalink();
$url = urlencode($myurl);
```

The second is that there are no functions defined named `twitter_tweet_count`, `facebook_like_share_count`, or `pinterest_pins`. Instead you've assigned them to variables using anonymous functions to determine their value.

Essentially you should be able to change this

```
echo twitter_tweet_count( 'http://www.bendaggers.com/how-to-write-a-killer-resume-that-lands-an-interview/' );
```

... to this

```
echo $twitter_tweet_count( 'http://www.bendaggers.com/how-to-write-a-killer-resume-that-lands-an-interview/' );
```

... with the only difference being the `$` before the `twitter_tweet_count` text.

Once that's fixed you should further be able to combine both fixes, with the final product looking something like this (using the dynamic value of `$url`):

```
<?php

$myurl = get_permalink();
$url = urlencode($myurl);

$facebook_like_share_count = function ( $url ) {
    $api = file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $url );
    $count = json_decode( $api );
    return $count->shares;
};

$twitter_tweet_count = function ( $url ) {
    $api = file_get_contents( 'https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $url );
    $count = json_decode( $api );
    return $count->count;
};

$pinterest_pins = function ( $url ) {
    $api = file_get_contents( 'http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback%20&url=' . $url );
    $body = preg_replace( '/^receiveCount\((.*)\)$/', '\\1', $api );
    $count = json_decode( $body );
    return $count->count;
};

echo $twitter_tweet_count( $url );

echo "<br>";

echo $facebook_like_share_count( $url );

echo "<br>";

echo $pinterest_pins( $url );

echo "<br>";

?>
```

Comment: I got this error: Warning: file_get_contents(http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Falphaomega.bendaggers.com%2F2014%2F10%2F25%2Flegendary-moments-of-barney-stinson%2F): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in

Answer (score 2):

Read the last error code you gave in comments : 403 (forbiden access)

So I gone on the facebook API docs and found this : [Link to docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests#errors)

> Its possible that one of your requested operations may throw an error.
>   This could be because, for example, you don't have permission to
>   perform the requested operation.

In the example that following this quote, we can see a 403 response code to the request.

Well, I have access to this page from my navigator and from PHP file_get_contents function. So maybe you are blacklisted, or there are some quotas ... If problem persists you should contact Facebook to know why your server does not have access to this information.

```
{
   "id": "http://alphaomega.bendaggers.com/2014/10/25/legendary-moments-of-barney-stinson/",
   "shares": 4
}
```

Hope its helped :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to avoid this error.

## 1st method

If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with urlencode().

```
urlencode - This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.
```

Check out the code below

```
$myurl = get_permalink();
$url = urlencode($url);
```

## 2nd method

`file_get_contents()` utilizes the `fopen()` wrappers, therefore it is restricted from accessing URLs through the `allow_url_fopen` option within `php.ini`.

[Should I allow 'allow_url_fopen' in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127534/should-i-allow-allow-url-fopen-in-php)

## 3rd method

You can try curl. Try this [link](http://codular.com/curl-with-php).