# Telegram + PHP (Windows 7): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: php, telegram, apache2.4, php-5.6, telegram-bot

I'm trying to move my first steps in Telegram and I'm also a newbie in PHP ......

I've configured, on my Windows 7 pc, Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.6.14 and SSL and it's working fine in http and https.

Then I've tried to follow this Telegram Bot Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJBYojK7DO4. Everything works fine until when I have to create a simple PHP program like this one

```
<?php
  $botToken = "<my_bot_token>";
  $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken; 
  $update = file_get_contents($website."/getUpates"); 
  print_r($update);
?>
```

When I try to put in my browser

```
https://localhost/Telegram/MyYouTubeTutorialBot/YouTubeTutorialBot.php
```

the response is

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/<my_bot_token>/getupates): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in <my_php_file_location> on line 6
```

I've searched on the web for similar issues but nothing has solved: the most interesting response is in this question [file_get_contents - failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574130/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-404-not) but I don't understand how to adapt it to my case.

In others responses there is the suggestion to use curl but I'd like to solve continuing file_get_contents function.

I think that it's not a PHP problem but something in my configurations somewhere ... bu I don't know where

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance

Cesare

**NOTE ADDED**

There was a typo spelling error in my original code as @aeryaguzov suggest in the comments ....

Here you're the fixed code that works right now ...

```
<?php
  $botToken = "<my_bot_token>";
  $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken; 
  $update = file_get_contents($website."/getUpdates"); 
  print_r($update);
?>
```

Comment: I  see <my_bot_token> in your warning. Do you send real token instead of this placeholder?

Comment: yes! there is a real token .......

Comment: maybe you're just using the wrong url...try   $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot/".$botToken.'/'; , also, what does var_dump(base64_encode($website));  give you?

Comment: I've tried but nothing change .... the result of var_dump(base64_encode($website)); is the following ......string(100) "aHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkudGVsZWdyYW0ub3JnL2JvdDE3MDE4NDEwMzpBQUVKbUVzbXo1MVVFbTM5aDc2T3NxcUlrVEZGX1MzNUQ4dw=="

Comment: I checked telegram API and see only "getUpdates" method but not  "getupates". Check spelling please

Comment: @aeryaguzov thanks .... good notes, but it's not the solution unfortunately .... in any case I've fix my code (also in my initial question ....), and now I'm using getUpdate function ....

Comment: @Cesare you have invalid spelling again: use "getUpdates" but not "getUpates"

Comment: @aeryaguzov .... You're right!!!! A very, great, STUPID error ..... sorry!! But thanks a lot for the support.... .Now it's working fine ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a PHP problem something in your configurations.
the error means that the file `https://api.telegram.org/<my_bot_token>/getupates` does not exist.

Comment: I don't think so because putting the same http request in a browser give a right response ....

Answer (score 0):

The Telegram API always returns *something* in it's body. In the case of an error this is a JSON object with `ok` set to `false`, an `error_code` and a `description` field. However, it also sets the response header to the relevant error code, causing `file_get_content()` to throw an error instead of returning the still very useful body. To circument this you can add a stream context like so:

```
<?php
    $stream_context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array (
            'ignore_errors' => true
         )
    ));

    $botToken = "<my_bot_token>";
    $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
    $update = file_get_contents($website."/getUpdates", false, $stream_context);
    print_r($update);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error. You can Try check with JSON then it is because of the webhook is running

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can't use getUpdates method while webhook is active"}
```

you should delete the webhook for your bot API by 
...../setwebhook without url.