# PHP file_get_contents sometimes failed to open stream Http request failed

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have an ajax call that gets many, many pages of contents from a website, but it fails to open steams sometimes even though the same exact links that failed to open streams works just fine, when I ran them again. The problem is, then other links would failed to open stream. Anyone know why this is happening?

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.merriam-webster.com/browse/dictionary/a/acoustically.htm): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

Comment: Maybe a problem with their network; the server's connection you are executing the code on; or they limit the number of requests.

Comment: @chris85 Can I fix this by using a while loop, that keep trying to get their contents when there's not a match?

Comment: Yea, you could use a `while` to execute it until you get a response although if there server is down you will enter an infinite loop.

Comment: I made a sample code to test this and 46 out of 500 requests to that page failed. It didn't seem to be a fixed number of requests but could have been a time filter (e.g. 2 requests a seconds per IP).

Comment: @chris85 Haha. That explains it then. I limited my ajax callback to 100 milliseconds!

Comment: Yea, looks like that is against their TOS, might run into issues in the future too. `You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on the Services, except with our express written permission.` or this is what I see it as happening I'll leave this up to another user though that perhaps has more experience with this.

Comment: @chris85 Well, looks like it's time to use that while loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents - failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574130/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-404-not)