# Simple html dom not working for a table[class]

Tags: php, html, dom, include

I want to use the contents of a website and include them in mine with ["Simple Html DOM"](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), unfortunately the code which normally works for another  websites, fails in this specific case:

```
<?php

// Note you must download the php files from the link above 
// and link to them on this line below. 
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');


$html = file_get_html('http://www.comelmar.it/index.aspx?idmnu=23&midx=3&mbidx=2&idmnub=8&Lang=EN');
$elem = $html->find('table[class=Descrizione]', 0);
echo $elem;

?>
```

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://www.comelmar.it/index.aspx?idmnu=23&midx=3&mbidx=2&idmnub=8&Lang=EN)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in
>   public_html/elin-custom-code/simple_html_dom.php on
>   line 75
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
>   public_html/elin-custom-code/sklad-1.php on line 9

Comment: It looks like the page requires a user agent or something. It is throwing a 500 which means there is an error. Your `Fatal error` is because `$html` is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a link for the reference:-

[file_get_contents - failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574130/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-404-not)

**Most hosting provides now block the `furl_open` parameter which allows you to use `file_get_contents()` to load data from an external url.**

You can use `CURL` or a `PHP` client library like `Guzzle`.

To be make sure i just use `CURL` to check what is the exact problem with the help of below code:-

```
<?php
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.comelmar.it/index.aspx?idmnu=23&midx=3&mbidx=2&idmnub=8&Lang=EN');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
echo "<pre/>";print_r($query);
?>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/a91nl5

So it seems that for security reason these method calls(`CURL` and `file_get_contents`) are blocked on that site.

You can try this link answers also, may be you will get some useful output:-

[PHP file_get_contents() returns "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/why-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed)

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

If I understood you correctly, it is not possible due to security reasons?

Comment: It looks like, that's why i gave you two links along with my effort . Some more answers are there, you need to check and try them. May be you can get something useful. For me it seems security is the problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for marking. If not up-voted then up-vote too.