# Google Drive API - PHP - failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I got

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

in php when got file from Google Drive through **Google Drive API**.

My code below:

```
public function actionGetAllImagesFromDrive($fid, $path)
    {
        $client = $this->getGoogleClient();
        $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);

        $optParams = array(
            'q' => "'$fid' in parents and trashed=false",
            'fields' => '*'
        );
        $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

        $folderMimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder';

        if (count($results->getFiles()) != 0) {
            if (!is_dir($path)) {
                mkdir($path, 0775, true);
            }
            foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
                if($file->getMimeType() == $folderMimeType) {
                    $this->actionGetAllImagesFromDrive($file->getId(), $path .'/'.$file->getName());
                } else {
                    $url = $file->getWebContentLink();

                    $file_name = $path .'/'. $file->getName();
                    print_r("Downloading: ".$file->getName()."\n");
                    file_put_contents( $file_name, file_get_contents($url));
                }
            }

        } else {
            print_r("Folder is empty.\n");
        }
    }
```

This code will get all image from folder and  sub folder on Google Drive.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574130/)?

Comment: Something tells me your file doesnt exist.

Comment: Hi @DaImTo, I sure that this file exist because I scanned folder on drive and `getWebContentLink` if it's file.

Comment: Hi @RafaGuillermo, I tried to use `curl` and `guzzle` but it's still showing the same error.

Comment: do a files.list and list all the files you have access to.

Comment: Yes, I is owner of folder

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered following the example in the library [large file download](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/large-file-download.php)

```
// Determine the file's size and ID
$fileId = $files[0]->id;
$fileSize = intval($files[0]->size);

// Get the authorized Guzzle HTTP client
$http = $client->authorize();

// Open a file for writing
$fp = fopen('Big File (downloaded)', 'w');

// Download in 1 MB chunks
$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
$chunkStart = 0;

// Iterate over each chunk and write it to our file
while ($chunkStart < $fileSize) {
  $chunkEnd = $chunkStart + $chunkSizeBytes;
  $response = $http->request(
    'GET',
    sprintf('/drive/v3/files/%s', $fileId),
    [
      'query' => ['alt' => 'media'],
      'headers' => [
        'Range' => sprintf('bytes=%s-%s', $chunkStart, $chunkEnd)
      ]
    ]
  );
  $chunkStart = $chunkEnd + 1;
  fwrite($fp, $response->getBody()->getContents());
}
```