# PHP try-catch not working

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

```
try     
{
    $matrix = Query::take("SELECT moo"); //this makes 0 sense

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($matrix, MYSQL_BOTH)) //and thus this line should be an error
    {

    }

    return 'something';
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    return 'nothing';   
}
```

However instead of just going to catch part and returning `nothing` it shows a warning `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given` in the line starting with `while`. I have never came up to using exceptions in php, but used them a lot in C# and it seems in PHP they are working differently or, as always, I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Here are some like your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning

Comment: Read this http://phpmaster.com/error-handling-in-php/

Comment: @SirDarius - Interesting and worthwhile reading link. Thanks :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can't handle Warnings/Errors with try-catch blocks, because they aren't exceptions. If you want to handle warnings/errors, you have to register your own error handler with [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

But it's better to fix this issue, because you could prevent it.

Comment: building on this answer, you could easily set set_error_handler to capture PHP errors and issue an Exception, at which point your try-catch will work. I am sure you can Google for something suitable.

Comment: For throwing exceptions, set_error_handler should be used in combination with ErrorException (built-in class specifically for this use).

Comment: I've been doing php full time for a few years now, and I didn't even know this.

Comment: You can *not* prevent users from using incorrect authentication credentials via `imap_open` so no, you can't prevent it.

Answer (score 39):

Exception is only subclass of Throwable. To catch error you can try to do one of the following:

```
try {

    catch (\Exception $e) {
       //do something when exception is thrown
}
catch (\Error $e) {
  //do something when error is thrown
}
```

OR more inclusive solution

```
try {

catch (\Exception $e) {
   //do something when exception is thrown
}
catch (\Throwable $e) {
  //do something when Throwable is thrown
}
```

BTW : Java has similar behaviour.

Comment: I used `\Exception` instead of `Exception` and it worked. Can you elaborate on how a \ (slash) before `Exception` makes a huge difference here?

Comment: @Shashanth using `Exception` without a slash assumes you've got a `use Exception;` statement at the top, or aren't using namespacing, the `\ ` makes it look in the global PHP namespace, so it'll catch a PHP `Exception` and any classes based on it - official documentation: https://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

Comment: In modern PHP, with the use of namespaces, the inclusion of the ' \ ' is essential.

Comment: Genius, you saved my day!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Unlike some other languages, PHP has different sets of errors to handle. Fatal errors won't be handled if you only catch the Exception class.

Answer (score 6):

In PHP a warning is not an exception. Generally the best practice would be to use defensive coding to make sure the result is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 4):

Welp, unfortunately this is the issue about PHP. Try/catch statements will catch Exceptions, but what you're receiving is an old-school PHP error.

You'll have to catch an error like this with:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Either that or check to see if $matrix is a mysqli_result object prior to performing mysqli_fetch_array.

Comment: Old-school PHP error handling worked for me. Thank you for pointing me in that right direction!

Answer (score 1):

PHP is generating a warning, not an exception. Warnings can't be caught. They are more like compiler warnings in C#.