# Is there a way to find out if a method is static or not?

Tags: php, static-methods

Is there a way to find out if a method is static or not?

My reason for needing to know:
I call static methods outside of any instantiation context. Non-static methods can't be called then, since they don't make sense yet. I want to call them later, once instances of those classes exist.

When I call `call_user_function_array($className.'::'.$functionName, $args);` and the method is non-static, php seems to automatically create an instance of className and call that function. I want that call to FAIL for non-static functions.

Comment: "php seems to automatically create an instance of className and call that function" - it's not true.

Comment: @sectus: Why would those calls not fail then?

Comment: Use E_STRICT error level.

Comment: @sectus: stil is not reporting an error. I'll try to condense my code down to an example and post it.

Comment: "Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning. " - [Static Keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: @sectus: Of course you where right. I figured out why I wasn't getting that error. inside `__callStatic` i made another call to `call_user_function_array`, this time with an instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since reflection is expensive I actually ended up calling `set_error_handler` with a callback that throws an ErrorException as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning) to catch the warning when a static call was made to a non-static method.

Comment: You *really* like spaghetti code, do you? To dynamically call methods you don't even know on objects you have no idea about you override the global error handler to catch exceptions...?! Sorry, but that boggles the mind.

Comment: I'm not saying anything for or against the PHP error handling system, you're right that it's not exactly great. I'm saying that you seem to be going to quite some lengths for something that seems like a dubious practice to begin with, and your code is probably going to be really hard to maintain or understand because of it. You're very much indulging in meta-programming there, which makes things harder to understand in almost any language, and you're doing it in a language that really isn't all that well suited for meta-programming to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

> When I call `call_user_function_array($className.'::'.$functionName, $args);`
>   and the method is non-static, php seems to automatically
>   create an instance of className and call that function.

No, it doesn't. PHP isn't *that* automagic. No idea what you're doing there.

To call a method statically, you do exactly that:

```
call_user_func_array("$className::$functionName", $args);
```

To call a method of an object, *you* first need to explicitly instantiate an object, then call it like this:

```
$obj = new MyClass;
call_user_func_array(array($obj, $method), $args);
```

To programmatically figure out if a method is static or not, use [`ReflectionClass`](http://www.php.net/ReflectionClass):

```
$r = new ReflectionClass($myClass);
$m = $r->getMethod($method);
var_dump($m->isStatic());
```

You should really *know* what a method is before you call it though, instead of dynamically trying to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the warning at the end. Trust me, I know what I am doing... I know those are some famous last words.... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can check methods with reflection.

```
class foo
    {
    static public function bar()
        {}

    public function baz()
        {}
    }

$reflection_class = new ReflectionClass('foo');

var_dump($reflection_class->getMethod('bar')->isStatic()); // boolean true
var_dump($reflection_class->getMethod('baz')->isStatic()); // boolean false
```

P.S. It's very weird that you trying to call methods but you do not know what they really are.