# get_headers is throwing a warning instead of just returning false?

Tags: php

According to the docs

[get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

should return false if a header request fails.

However, it is breaking my code w/ this warning:

> **Warning**:  get_headers(http://ideone.com/) [function.get-headers]: failed to open
>   stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service
>   not known in
>   **some.php** on line **21**

I wanted to test that a given url was available using code similar to this:

```
$res[$i] = (get_headers($temp[$i]) == false);
```

Comment: That's also what the first comment says. And the rest of the manual page doesn't contraire that, and it's not exactly unexpected for lower-level errors (here: DNS resolution). Is this a complaint or a question?

Answer (score 10):

I don't think this is a doc bug; at least internally, it uses the common implementation for opening streams to some location.

And so this function will throw the same warnings like every other function using the internal `php_stream_open_wrapper_ex`, when passing a) an invalid address or b) an unreachable address.

If you want to suppress this warning, prepend `get_headers` with an `@`:

```
$res[$i] = (@get_headers($temp[$i]) === false);
```

Comment: @OneTrickPony yes. CURL uses the libcurl, which naturally doesn't affect any error handling of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the first comment on the [php man page of get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

It seems like it's working as expected.

So you must either disable warnings, either find a workaround.

After a quick search, I found this [post on phpfreaks](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/169441-get-headers-problems/) that might help you.
The solution used there is to use [gethostbyname](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.gethostbyname.php) first to resolve the IP address of the server, then retrieve the headers if it doesn't return false.

Or more simply, disable the warning with an `@` before the call. (See [Can I try/catch a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning) and [php's error reporting page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php))

Comment: I can't see why you couldn't if it is just throwing you warnings.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php to have more info on this `@`.