# fopen() [function.fopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, cakephp

```
$url=$row1['content_url'];
$file_handle = fopen($url,"r");
$line=fread($file_handle,400);
$line1 = wordwrap($line,400,"</br>" );
fclose($file_handle);
```

the above give is my code for reading data in the text file...
it is working fine in my localhost...
But it is not working in serevr.....

> Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in
>   /home/content/08/11968108/html/dev/index.php on line 57
>
> Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /home/content/08/11968108/html/dev/gopi/index.php on line 58
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /home/content/08/11968108/html/dev/gopi/index.php on line 60

Comment: Check if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled on your live server.

Comment: What does `$url` contain?

Comment: URL does not exist or is not reachable.

Comment: Url Contain the textfile path... (www.xyx.com/content/some.txt)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the URL in `$url` contains a wrapper (like `http`).

**Explanation**

```
fopen("www.domain.com","r");
```

This will look for a local file named www.domain.com

```
fopen("http://www.domain.com","r");
```

This will try to get the external file `http://www.domain.com` (if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled)

But your error could also indicate an old cached DNS record. If you can, try to change your name server on the production system (e.g.: `8.8.8.8` for the name server from google).

Comment: Yeah, browsers are doing a pretty good job at protecting users from URLs :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to **handle the warnings** that are thrown (as I did), you may just do this to turn them into *Exceptions* that can be handled:

```
set_error_handler(
  function ($err_severity, $err_msg, $err_file, $err_line, array $err_context) {
    // do not throw an exception if the @-operator is used (suppress)
    if (error_reporting() === 0) return false;

    throw new ErrorException( $err_msg, 0, $err_severity, $err_file, $err_line );
  },
  E_WARNING
);
try {
  $fp = fopen("http://example.com","r");
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
restore_error_handler();
```

Solution based on this [thread/question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1241728/6225838).