# How to catch warning/fatal inside php c-extension?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

If I do something inside my extension that could produce `warnings` or `fatals`, how I can `catch` them?

I suppose that some `global` variables control this, but don't know which one.

Comment: My PHP expertise is limited so I might miss the obvious but to which kind of "*warnings or fatals*" are you referring to?

Comment: In userspace of PHP we can call `set_error_handler` for errors catching. I need this feature inside C code. I guess there is global variable for this.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning

Comment: This one for userspace PHP. I asked about C-API.

Answer (score 0):

C does not know exceptions, try/catch/finally are not avaliable.

You need to use other mechanics to detect errors and handle them.

Ok, ok - there is `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`, but ...

Comment: There are `zend_try {` and `} zend_end_try();`, for example.