# Suppress specific MySQL warning message

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

We're getting a `Headers and client library minor version mismatch` message and we have a path to resolving the actual warning, but for now we need to suppress it.

But! We need to keep all other warnings.

So, is there a way to suppress this single error message?

Comment: FYI - I know I can use `@` to suppress errors from a single line of code, but that would require suppressing ALL MySQL errors, not just this one.

Comment: nope. can't be done short of recompiling php. there isn't fine-grained enough control of warnings/errors to disable one specific error, only specific TYPES of errors.

Comment: Well, you can set up [your own error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) – and if that particular warning occurs, ignore/absorb it, and for everything else output and/or log the interesting parts of the error yourself. If you don’t want it to affect your overall application too much, you can do so just before the warning occurs, and [restore PHP’s original error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.restore-error-handler.php) afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_error_handler` and check for the specific message, then just return false in cases where you want the use default error handling

E.G

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if (false === strpos($errstr, 'Headers and client library minor version mismatch')) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error only occurs once in a request lifecycle (i.e. when connecting to the database, a [temporary custom error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241751/4623317) could silence the warning if it matches a condition.

Alternatively [ship logs](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) through a processor like [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) for realtime filtering and graphing.