# How to flash a error message before deleting a non empty directory

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to delete a directory associated to a record but not if the directory is not empty although I know by default we cannot delete a non empty dir by `rmdir()` and it will flash an error. But this is a compiler error and I want to print a error within the application telling the user why the dir can not be deleted. basically what I'm looking for is something like this:-

```
 public function actionDelete($id)
 if(some condition here to check the dir is empty)
 {
        rmdir("path of the dir")
 }else {
       a flash msg here saying directory is not empty 
 }
```

provided that using `yii2` framework of php.

Comment: Here is an answer how to catch E_WARNING http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setFlash()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#setFlash%28%29-detail) method for Flash Message.

For example,

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
  try
  {
     rmdir("path of the dir")
  }
  catch(Exception $e) 
  {
     Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Custom error message or catched exception.')); 
  }
}
```

Comment: it is still showing compiler error not the flash error