# dns_get_record(): A temporary server error occurred.

Tags: php, laravel, exception, dns

I'm querying a whole bunch of addresses, some are online and some are not. I can't seem to get around this error however, even catching the exception fails :(

```
 dns_get_record(): A temporary server error occurred. 


        try {
            $result = dns_get_record('_minecraft._tcp.' . $addr, DNS_SRV);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return [$addr,$port];
        }
```

If this error occurs, I want to continue the script, skipping the record, however currently the script just halts.

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Define `catching the exception fails`, does it even throw an exception? Unless it throws an exception or fatal error the script shouldn't halt.

Comment: I get a 500 error that returns: dns_get_record(): A temporary server error occurred.

Comment: Check webserver logfiles

Comment: Sorry, I get 200 OK with

ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

dns_get_record(): A temporary server error occurred.

Comment: Then you're catching the wrong exception. You need to catch `ErrorException`.

Comment: That hasn't made a difference I'm afraid :(

Comment: @JoshUndefined The reason you can't catch this "Exception" is because it isn't an exception, it's a warning. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning for more details.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't catch this exception too. And how I understood it's a bug of php:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73149

But I found another solution. You can use `@` when you call this function. This symbol kill all errors when you call this one. And it will looks like that:

```
$dns = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_A);
if(!$dns){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It looks like this is the workaround for this PHP bug. While we ended up using an external DNS API (yes i know...) for this issue I'll mark this as the answer for anyone finding this question. Thanks!!

Comment: Longer description why https://dustri.org/b/a-short-tale-on-phps-dns_get_record.html

Comment: An exception is called if DNSSEC is not valid on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the IP (A record) for a host using the below PHP function

```
gethostbynamel(string $hostname): array|false
```

Reference: [gethostbynamel — Get a list of IPv4 addresses corresponding to a given Internet host name](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php)

Answer (score -6):

try this:

```
     try {
         $dns = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_A);
     }
     catch (Exception $e) {
         if ($e->getMessage() !== 'dns_get_record(): A temporary server error     occurred.') {
             throw $e;
         }
         $dns = false;
     }
```