# PHP exception handling - error not being catch

Tags: php, try-catch

So I have the following code:

```
try {
    if ($connectionid = ldap_connect($ldapserver)) {    
        $ldapbindid=ldap_bind($connectionid, $binddn, $bindpw);
        if ($mysearch = ldap_search($connectionid, $basedn, $query)) {
            //more LDAP code here
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    return false;
}
```

But because I'm supplying the wrong binddn and password, I'm getting a PHP error in the ldap_bind command.

```
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials
```

But reading my code, I understand I should get a boolean instead?

I have the impression that any errors that happens within the confines of the "try" section is going to be handled by the "catch" section. perhaps I'm understanding try/catch incorrectly?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your error is a PHP warning, which is not catchable. Only instances of `Exception` can be caught.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning) will help if you want to be able to "catch" the warning.