# how exceptions(try, catch) work in php?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I don't exactly know how exceptions work. as I assume, they should avoid php errors and display "my error message". for example, i want to open file

```
class File{

   public $file;

   public function __construct($file)
   {
       try{
           $this->file = fopen($file,'r');
       }
       catch(Exception $e){
           echo "some error" . $e->getMessage();
       }
     }
  }

  $file = new File('/var/www/html/OOP/texts.txt');
```

it works. now I intentionally change the file name `texts.txt` to `tex.txt` just to see an error message from my catch block, but instead, php gives an error `Warning: fopen(/var/www/html/OOP/texts.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/OOP/file.php on line 169` . so it's php error, it doesn't display error message from catch block. What am I doing wrong? how exactly try/catch  works?

Comment: because "Warning" is not an error. You can only catch exceptions that actually get thrown. So for this example you'll have to code your own verification that you actually got a file opened.

Comment: read here how to "catch" a warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning

Comment: Not every PHP statement/function throws Exceptions. You can only catch what is thrown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PHP manual

> If the open fails, an error of level E_WARNING is generated. You may
>   use @ to suppress this warning.

`fopen` returns FALSE on error so you could test for that and throw an exception which would be caught. Some native PHP functions will generate exceptions, others raise errors.

```
class File{
   public $file;

   public function __construct($file){
       try{

           $this->file = @fopen($file,'r');
           if( !$this->file ) throw new Exception('File could not be found',404);

       } catch( Exception $e ){
           echo "some error" . $e->getMessage();
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. can you please tell me, if i have to add `@` and also check for false/null  `if( !$this->file )` then whats the point of using try catch? it seems like i can check file with `if` operators without try catch and result would be the same

Comment: @მაზა ფაკა The `try{}catch` Block can be outside the class if you want, but that  `if()` that you want to use can not outside the class. Read more into the Topic ExeptionHandling, ExeptionTypes UserDefinedExeptions :-)

Comment: The `try-catch` block should be used outside the class, it's pretty useless within the method where you throw the exception.

Comment: I think i should go more deep in exceptions to know how the works. thank you guys