# Why this Exception can not be handled by catch try method

Tags: php

When i initiate a class which does not exist , It throws the error, I Don't want to halted by that error . So i try `trycatch` method , But it  still giving me same error, Can someone explain why this error is not been catched
I tried

```
 try{$obj = new classname();}
 catch(Exception $e){ echo 'class does not exist, move on' ;}
```

#### Fatal error: Class 'classname' not found in C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\localhost\webroot\index.php on line 4

Can someone explain why this error can not be catched ?

Is their is another way to catch and handle this kind of errors ?

### UPDATE

We can catch `mysql` fatal errors by try catch method , So don't say fatal errors can not be handeled by try catch method

Comment: Because it's not an exception, it's a fatal error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning

Comment: Exceptions are generated by running code which encounters an error.  Your code isn't able to run, so a try/catch doesn't do anything.  You'd correct this by not trying to instantiate a class which doesn't exist.

Comment: Regarding your update... MySQL errors and PHP errors are very, very different things.  PHP *can* catch runtime errors generated by failing database queries, because the PHP code is itself running without error.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Can u explain why database Fatal errors can be handle by try catch method.,

Comment: Because `catch` catches exceptions not errors.  Check the link I posted.  Also: _We can catch mysql fatal errors by try catch method_  Really? Show me?

Comment: @user7025447: When integrating with the database, the PHP code is simply communicating with an external system.  That external system can fail, but the PHP code itself hasn't failed.  It can successfully detect that failure and handle it accordingly.  However, if you write PHP code which itself is invalid and can't execute, then it can't self-detect its own failure.  Code has to be able to execute in order to handle exceptions.

Comment: @AbraCadaver In PHP 7, catch catches throwables, including the error class ;)

Comment: @Xorifelse: Good to know!  What are the chances OP is using PHP 7?

Comment: @David Thanks david and all other members for replying. I don't really understand whats going on but got the idea :D

Comment: @AbraCadaver Read your comment wrong, read changes instead of chances, but.. apparently he has PHP 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to solve this, use a autoloader that runs a custom written function for each object that does not exist so you can try to "include" a file on demand.

```
function autoload($objname){
  if(is_readable(($f = '/path/to/class/'.$objname.'.php'))){
    include $f;
  } else {
    throw Exception("$f does not exist");
  }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload');

new classname(); // try to load /path/to/class/classname.php
```

Or you can upgrade to PHP 7 where the error logic has had little overhaul:

### Hierarchy

- Throwable

  - Error

    - ArithmeticError
    - DivisionByZeroError
    - AssertionError
    - ParseError
    - TypeError
  - Exception

So a code like this would work:

```
try{
  $obj = new classname();
} catch(Error $er){
  echo 'class does not exist, move on';
} catch(Exception $ex){
  echo 'a custom exception has been thrown:' . $ex->getMessage();
} catch(Throwable $t){
  // Obsolete code, as Throwables are either Error or Exception, that were caught above.
}
```

Comment: it is not working i tried,`try{
 $obj = new classname();
} catch(Error $er){
  echo 'class does not exist, move on';`  But still the same error

Comment: Then perhaps, you already have a working autoloader somewhere, generating that exception? Instead change `Error` to `Throwable` as it will catch that custom exception as well.