# How do I know if I've exceeded maximum request parameters?

Tags: php

Supposed I'm receiving an HTTP request. I try to access it, but because it has lots and lots of data, PHP's `max_input_vars` directive effectively cuts some of the parameters from request: When I try to access the request using e.g. `$_REQUEST`, some of the data is missing. **How do I know when this happens?**

For some background:

I know I can get `count($_REQUEST)` and compare it to the value returned by `ini_get('max_input_vars')`, but I would like to write foolproof code where I can detect exceeding the limit by even one. Another drawback of this method is that when passing lists etc., each list element becomes a separate request parameter that counts towards the limit, but PHP parses them into a single array again. For example, something like `list = [1, 2, 3]` is passed as something like this in the request:

```
list[]=1
list[]=2
list[]=3
```

After PHP parses this into, say, `$_REQUEST`, it's a single array (i.e. `$_REQUEST['list']`) again, which causes `count($_REQUEST)` to not return the wanted value. It's possible to get around this but it's not the most convenient thing to do.

Comment: Just for the record: I have a work-around where I manually compute the number of items in both ends and pass the number as one of the parameters. It's fairly hacky though, and I was curious if there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

> If there are more input variables than specified by this directive, an `E_WARNING` is issued...

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention it but that part is clear. I would like to do this in code so I can react to the situation, preferably to respond with an error of some sort. As it is, this is of course a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @Xiyng Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning for strategies for that. It's entirely possible to catch and act on an `E_WARNING`.

Comment: Ooh, that's neat!