# Why PHP 7 doesn't catch some errors?

Tags: php

In **PHP 7** the base interface for any object that can be thrown is [Throwable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php). We also have an [Error](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) base class for all internal PHP errors. But why then I can't catch errors like:

**a)**

```
try {
    $file = fopen('not_exist_file', 'r');
} catch (\Error $e) {
    echo 'Cannot open a file';
}
```

**Expected result**: 'Cannot open a file'
**Actual result**: PHP Warning:  fopen(not_exist_file): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

**b)**

```
try {
    $result = 10 / 0;
} catch(\DivisionByZeroError $e){
    echo 'Catch DivisionByZeroError';
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    echo 'Catch Throwable';
}
```

**Expected result**: 'Catch DivisionByZeroError'
**Actual result**: PHP Warning:  Division by zero in ..

**c)**

```
try {
    trigger_error('User error');
} catch(\Error $e) {
    echo 'Catch error';
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    echo 'Catch throwable';
}
```

**Expected result**: 'Catch error'
**Actual result**: PHP Notice:  User error in ..

My PHP version 7.1.1 (cli)

Comment: _“But why then I can't catch errors like […]”_ - _because_ they are simple errors. You can only _catch_ what someone _threw_ in the first place, and fopen or a division by zero simply don’t do anything like that.

Comment: The errors you listed are not caught because they are not thrown. They are not exceptions but traditional errors that are [triggered](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) by the PHP code since its very beginning, years before the exceptions and OOP were introduced in the language.

Comment: To "catch" these language level errors you need to set a custom error handler - http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: One reason they are WARNING and not ERRORS [See this for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The errors you listed are not caught because they are not thrown. They are not exceptions but traditional errors that are [triggered](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) by the PHP code since its very beginning, years before the exceptions and OOP were introduced in the language.

You can, however, [install an error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) that can handle the errors by creating and throwing [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) objects for them.
The documentation of the [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) class includes a simple example of how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Not all PHP functions throw exceptions. Exceptions are an OO concept, whereas these are plain old PHP functions.

Always check the manual to see what the return is result!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php