# How to echo php error (ftp_get)

Tags: php

I get files thanks to ftp_get but sometimes it does not work, so I would like to know how to write them in a modal or directly in my database

```
Warning: ftp_get(): File not found
```

For example when I have this error, I would only like to recover `File not found` in a variable

Or `File currently locked by another user` for `Warning: ftp_get(): File currently locked by another user`

I use Php 7.2 so I can not use [$php_errormsg](http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php)

Comment: Maybe http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php is better? Although you should turn off the display errors and then just control how a `false` return is handled

Comment: Take a read through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning

Comment: @user3783243 I have this error : `Notice: Array to string conversion` when I add : `echo error_get_last()`

Comment: It is an array, not a string. `print_r(error_get_last())`

Comment: Thanks, it's work