# Turning PHP warnings into User defined Exception

Tags: php, file-upload, php-5.6

Language Used: PHP
Version: 5.6

I am trying to upload a file to the server with the following function:

```
move_uploaded_file($source,$destination);
```

Whenever file fails to upload due to any reason such as

Permission denied,

No Destination folder found,

etc

It simply raises a warning and continues with other parts of the code.
But I want to catch that warning and change the flow of the program if any of the warnings are raised with their name so that I can throw appropriate Exception.

I am currently using `try{}catch(){}` block to upload a file but an exception is not raised for the warning.

***Edited***
Found this...

```
move_uploaded_file($source,$destination);
```

returns true or false based on status of file upload. But it does not specify reason. How to know that?

Comment: It's a warning, so it won't throw it's own exception. [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) returns false if it fails, so you can always throw your own exception there.

Comment: @aynber Thanks for your input. But, what if want to know the reason behind failure of file upload?

Comment: You might want to look here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning). Using the error handler should allow you to get more information.

Comment: In the error handler you can then look for `Permission denied` etc...

Answer (score 0):

I guess `set_error_handler()` would be the right choice. Make sure your read the documentation carefully.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php.

First, you'd need an function (or public class-method) to handle the error.
Example:

```
function error_handler($code, $text, $file, $line) {
    echo sprintf('code: %s, text: %s, file: %s, line: %s', $code, $text, $file, $line );

    return false; // continue with PHPs error handling
}
```

Second, call `set_error_handler` somewhere in your init/bootstrap code. Specify your error_handler method and set appropriate flags for which situations you want to be informed.

```
$flags = E_ALL & ~(E_STRICT | E_NOTICE);
set_error_handler('error_handler', $flags);
error_reporting($flags);
```

A word of warning: If you intend to catch errors like out-of-memory, your code should be prepared to use as less memory as possible. Also resources may not be available anymore (like database connections or file handles).