# php7.3 ftp_cdup() throws "CDUP successful" exception in some FTP servers

Tags: php, ftp

```
for($i=1;$i<=$path_div;$i++)         
{
    try{
        $res = ftp_cdup($this->conn);
        if(!$res){
            throw new \Exception('ftp_cdup fail');
        }
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        /**
         * :ftp_cdup(): CDUP successful. "/" is current directory
         */
        if(strpos($e->getMessage(),'ftp_cdup(): CDUP successful')>=0){
            //normal
        }else{
            throw new \Exception('ftp_cdupfail:'.$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Exception is

> ftp_cdup(): CDUP successful. "/" is current directory

In fact this is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I do not think that `ftp_cdup` (nor any other PHP FTP function) throws any exception. You probably have some error handler in place that [converts PHP warnings into exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1241728/850848), don't you?

---

Anyway, PHP expects that the server responds with code 250 to a successful `CDUP` command. Your server probably responds with some other 2xx success code (like plain 200). I do not think that PHP is right here. And I do not think you can really do anything about it.

Instead of using `ftp_cdup`, you can do:

```
$resp = ftp_raw("CDUP");
```

And check the `$resp` for the 2xx code.

Or just use `ftp_chdir` instead of `ftp_cdup`.

---

I do not think that FTP RFC 959 really mandates that the response must be 200. It's just an example. The problem probably comes from the inconsistency in the examples for `CWD` and `CDUP`. I'd expect both to use the same code. But the RFC shows 250 for `CWD`, while 200 for `CDUP`. Even the RFC says that: *"The reply codes for CDUP be identical to the reply codes of CWD."*