# How to set to throw an exception for access array offset on value of type null in php

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I found a different behaviour when I run the following code in Laravel and in a simple php script.

```
try { 
    $a=null; $a[3]; 
    var_dump('ok'); 
} catch (\Exception $e) { 
    var_dump('error'); 
}
```

In Laravel it returns `error` but in the simple php script it returns `ok`.

I was wonder how can I set to return `error` in php script also.

Comment: I think it is because PHP classifies accessing and array offset on type null as a warning and not an exception. Take a look at this answer where it's explained how to catch warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning

Comment: @geertjanknapen thank you so much! So my Laravel is turning warnings into exceptions with a code like this: `set_error_handler(function ($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
    throw new \ErrorException($message, $severity, $severity, $file, $line);
});`

Comment: A bit late but I'm going to answer the question so it can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because PHP classifies "accessing an array offset on type null" as a warning and not as an exception. Since you only try to catch exceptions and are given warnings, it will never enter the catch block. Since under the hood Laravel translates warnings into exceptions, the catch block will be entered in Laravel and therefore output error.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning) will explain how to catch warnings.

Pretty sure you can also try your hand at editing the `register()` method in `Handler.php` to create a custom error handler, but there are probably plenty of guides online.