# PHP db connection issue with exception

Tags: php, database, exception

so this is my code:

```
<?php 

    class DB{

        private $host       = 'loscalhost';
        private $user       = 'root';
        private $password   = '';

        function __construct(){
            try {
                $connect_db = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);
            }catch(Exception $e){
                echo 'DB connection failed: ',  var_dump($e), "\n";
            }
        }
}
```

I changed the host variable value so i can display the message **DB connection failed...**, but my question is why is it not displayed? instead i get this: **Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known**

Comment: try private $host = 'localhost';

Comment: Please search for your problem first, this error message has even been asked and answered about. Additionally double check your code of typos as asking because of such little mistakes is off-topic. This works if you type the code you have a problem with as a new example with as little code as necessary to reproduce and from scratch (no copy and paste, not a single bit).

Comment: @hakre, my question is not about i mispelled the localhost

Comment: Then please make yourself comfortable with error reporting: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting - you control this with your php.ini. If you see the message on a production server PHP is not configured correctly. Please see this reference question: [Remove warning messages in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1987579/367456) - Again, please use the search.

Comment: And sure, you get the error message because you misspelled localhost. That's the reason why you ask. If you had not mispelled it, you wouldn't ask. :)

Comment: I'm happy to see such an intellectual person as you are, hakre, your logic is the best  :)

Answer (score 1):

Host name is `localhost` but you used `loscalhost`

```
 private $host = 'loscalhost';
```

should be

```
private $host = 'localhost';
```

Comment: please do not answer to questions that are obviously caused by a typo. additionally there is already a duplicate for this posting of an error message.