# Connect to database without writing warning/error messages

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using simple method to connect to my database:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8") or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
```

And its working fine, but when I directly typing wrong `$servername` (or else) then i got WARNING message:-

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'192.168.0.157' (using password: YES) in
>   C:\MAMP\htdocs\modul-1-froland\zaro_\admin\db_config.php on line 7

And then die message:

```
Unable to connect to MySQL
```

There is any solution to hide WARNING message, without @ and error_reporting(E_ALL)? I want to 'user friendly' error messages (like: Unable to connect to MySQL) and not the all error message (like mysqli_connect()...).

Comment: Didn't understood why not to use "error_reporting"?

Comment: hide warning :- `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);`

Comment: cause i think, there is another way to hide warning messages, but seems like no :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove warning messages in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987579/remove-warning-messages-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `or die` from the statement, which will stop the error message you are seeing.

Then if you want more friendly errors have a look at overriding the default php errors/exceptions.

User custom error handling [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and exception handler [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

Answer (score 2):

***To hide warning messages:-***

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

Different other settings are clearly described here:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2867082/4248328

Note:- personally I like to debug and found all errors and try to rectify them instead of hiding them (even if they are warnings or notices).Thanks

Comment: yes, me too, thats why i dont want use use error_report() and hide them, but thanks !