# Is there a way to catch Fatal error in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, fatal-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

I have this line of PHP code:

```
thisFunctionDoesNotExist();
```

And it stops script execution with:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function
```

I tried using set_error_handler and it does help for warning type of errors. But not for fatal errors. As I understand it from various threads on internet it should be possible to handle by set_error_handler, but I cannot make it work.

Can you please post working example?

Note: The code above is only an example. I don't need to detect that function exists. I am setting up general application error catcher.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked the duplicate. Voting to close too, since I cannot delete.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087365/php-try-catch-blocks-are-they-able-to-catch-invalid-arg-types

Comment: **See also:** https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41418

Answer (score 3):

Fatal errors cannot be caught.

Although not an answer to your question; if you have reasons to believe that function might not be around in all cases, check with function_exists();

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

```
$functionExists = function_exists("thisFunctionDoesNotExist");

iF($functionExists)
    thisFunctionDoesNotExist();
else
    die("failure");
```

Takes a string which is your function and returns true or false

Comment: Not the point of this question. The missing function is there just as an example.